# Mat2cell matlab equivalent in tensorflow or pytorch

Tags: tensorflow, matrix, pytorch

I have a square matrix and like to break it into some smaller matrices. For example, assume we have a matrix with the shape of `[4,4]` and would like to convert it into 4 smaller matrices with size `[2,2]`.

input:

```
[9, 9, 9, 9,
 8, 8, 8, 8,
 7, 7, 7, 7,
 6, 6, 6, 6]
```

output:

```
[[9, 9  | [9, 9,
 8, 8]  | 8, 8],
 ---------------
 [7, 7  | [7, 7,
 6, 6]  | 6, 6]]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given a tensor with the shape of `4*4` or `1*16` the easiest way to do this is by view function or reshape:

```
a = torch.tensor([9, 9, 9, 9, 8, 8, 8, 8, 7, 7, 7, 7, 6, 6, 6, 6])
# a = a.view(4,4)
a = a.view(2, 2, 2, 2)

# output:
tensor([[[[9, 9],
          [9, 9]],

         [[8, 8],
          [8, 8]]],


        [[[7, 7],
          [7, 7]],

         [[6, 6],
          [6, 6]]]])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use repeated calls to `torch.split` for this.

```py
>>> x
tensor([[ 1,  2,  3,  4],
        [ 5,  6,  7,  8],
        [ 9, 10, 11, 12],
        [13, 14, 15, 16]])
>>> [z for y in x.split(2) for z in y.split(2, dim=1)]
[tensor([[1, 2],
        [5, 6]]), tensor([[3, 4],
        [7, 8]]), tensor([[ 9, 10],
        [13, 14]]), tensor([[11, 12],
        [15, 16]])]
```